# What does $$FOO do in bash (in a deb package built with epm)?

Tags: bash, deb

On the command line, I get this:

```
$ FOO=foo
$ echo $FOO
foo
$ echo $$FOO
11971FOO
```

Here, $$ resolves to the PID of the shell as expected and "FOO" is printed verbatim.

Now, trying to understand and debug some scripts, I find the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=/path/to/file/1
FILE2=/path/to/file/2
echo $$FILE1 >> $$FILE2
```

The script in question originates from a postinstall script of a Debian package. Is this supposed to undergo pre-processing before it can run?

**Update:** The script is part of a package built with epm and read via the following directive:

```
%postinstall <script.sh
```

In the resulting deb package, the postinst script reads:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=/path/to/file/1
FILE2=/path/to/file/2
echo $FILE1 >> $FILE2
```

Thus, the processing is done by either epm or dpkg.

Comment: To me, this looks like a way to create a directory whose name does not collide with any existing one.

Comment: If that's an actual script, then it almost certainly is meant to be post-processed. It's impossible to say for sure, though, without more context.

Comment: To get this "double dereferencing" to work in bash, you'd use [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): `foo=bar; FOO=foo; echo "${!FOO}"` or, in bash v4, use a "name reference": `foo=bar; declare -n FOO=foo; echo "$FOO"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a feature of the EPM packaging tool. Quoting [the documentation](https://www.msweet.org/documentation/project2/EPM.html#5_2):

> Note that all commands specified in the list file will use the variable expansion provided by EPM, so be sure to quote any dollar sign ($) characters in your commands. For example, "$foo" is replaced by the value of "foo", but "$$foo" becomes "$foo".

Answer (score 0):

`$$` prints the process ID which is `11971` in your case.

Since you have a `FOO` after that `echo` just dumps `FOO` after `11971` so you get

```
11971FOO
```

To be precise it is the process id of the bash shell in which you 
run the session. To verify this you could do :

```
kill -9 11971
```

which will terminate the current session. The below script in normal cases

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=/path/to/file/1
FILE2=/path/to/file/2
echo $$FILE1 >> $$FILE2
```

will not undergo any preprocessing. It will keep on appending the file

```
current_shell_process_id_FILE2
```

in the current directory with the content

```
current_shell_process_idFILE1
```

Comment: The OP has made it clear that they already know what `$$` means by itself.

Comment: @TomFenech: Updated my answer.

Comment: @sjsam Thanks for your answer. I understand this. What I am wondering whether the quoted lines do something different in the context of a postinstall script.

Comment: @Jan : More information is needed in that case. In the post script is `globbing` disabled?

Comment: Globbing and parameter expansion are two different things.

Comment: @chepner : Thankyou for that. I got confused with the term. In fact I meant `parameter expansion`.

Comment: Paraemter expansion isn't something you can disable.